# How to put Python virtual environment base back from miniforge to anaconda?

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, virtualenv, mini-forge

```
conda env list

base           * /Users/miniforge3
                 /opt/anaconda3
                 /opt/anaconda3/envs/GitHub
                 /opt/anaconda3/envs/downgrade
                 /opt/anaconda3/envs/felix
```

Can I change the base to the route '/opt/anaconda3'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for `.condarc` in you profile path. Also refer to the documentation below. [config doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/config.html) to configure changes to your default config file.